# Add gsp pages and html functionality, to an application created using rest-api profile in grails?

Tags: grails, gsp

So I want to add gsp pages functionality to an application created using rest-api profile. So far I have tried the following. the gsp gets rendered but the layouts are not working.

```
in my build.gradle I added the following. 

buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-gradle:2.14.6"
    }
}


apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-web"
apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-gsp"
apply plugin:'asset-pipeline'



dependencies {
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-i18n"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:gsp"
    runtime "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-grails:2.14.6"
}
```

First of all, is this the correct way to do it or would I have to create a new application using the web profile.

Comment: "First of all, is this the correct way to do it or would I have to create a new application using the web profile." - It is not the case that you have to create a `web` app first. You can go in either direction. It will probably be easier to start with `web` because most of what you want for the REST stuff will be there, minus the `json-views` libraries which can be easily added.

Comment: Can I add gson views after I create my application using a web profile...

Comment: Yes, `json-views` is just a library you can add as a dependency.

Comment: See https://github.com/jeffbrown/webjsonviews/blob/efb2a363b7481d66f896deba0e7db5f1bfe3cd95/build.gradle.  That is a `web` profile app that has added `json-views`.  As you can see at https://github.com/jeffbrown/webjsonviews/tree/efb2a363b7481d66f896deba0e7db5f1bfe3cd95/grails-app/views/person, GSPs and gson files can co-exist.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with the help of someone called JB from the grails slack channel.

I was putting my templates inside the application folder i.e. grails-app/views/application/layout/main.gsp. The layout folder should be at the root of views i.e. at grails-app/views/layout/main.gsp .